# Solid closed triangle in $\mathbb{C}$ is compact?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading a proof of Goursat's theorem. In it, it states that a solid closed triangle is compact. Why is this true? I know what the definition of compact is but I cannot see intuitively why this would make such a triangle compact. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Do you know the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) (subsets of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ are compact if and only if they are closed and bounded)?

Comment: Oh my lord I completely brain farted and forgot about that. Thanks!